# Properly type dynamic functions in a proxy using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that returns a Proxy which uses a `get` trap to infer functions from multiple objects. Now I need to be able to type these functions, since they are technically known at compile time but TypeScript just can't figure them out. How do make TypeScript recognize these functions to be able to add them to my interface?

```
interface IObject {
  (): IFunction;
  addAMethod(name: string, fn: (...args: any[]) => any): void;
}

interface IFunction {
  list: string[];
  option: boolean;
}

const mainFunc: IObject = Object.assign(
  (): IFunction => {
    const context = {
      list: [],
      option: true,
    };

    return new Proxy(context, handler);
  },
  {
    addAMethod(name: string, fn: (...args: any[]) => any) {
      Object.assign(core, fn);
    },
  },
);

const handler = {
  get(context: {[key: string]: any}, prop: string, receiver: IFunction) {
    if (prop in context) {
      return context[prop];
    }
    if (prop in core) {
      return core[prop];
    }
  },
};

const core = {
  evaluate: (val: any) => true,
  doSomething: (val: any) => false
}

export default mainFunc;
```

Now this would allow one to the following:

```
import mainFunc from "./mainFunc"

mainFunc().evaluate('wow'); // Should return true
```

This of course does not return true but rather shows that `evaluate()` is not part of type `IFunction`, which is true. But when I try to add it I get another error, where I can't assign the function to `IFunction` because it does not define `evaluate()`.

```
// ...

interface IFunction {
  list: string[];
  option: boolean;
  evaluate(val: any): boolean;
}

const mainFunc: IObject = Object.assign(
  (): IFunction => {
    const context = {
      list: [],
      option: true,
    };

    return new Proxy(context, handler); // Error happens here
  },
  // ...
);

// ...

const core = {
  evaluate: (val: any) => true,
  doSomething: (val: any) => false
}
```

> Type '{ list: never[]; option: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IFunction'.
>     Property 'evaluate' is missing in type '{ list: never[]; option: boolean; }'.

Any idea how I could type `evaluate()`?

Comment: Just trying to understand the usage of `addAMethod` should that not have an extra `name` parameter to name the function that is being added ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir You're right, I've amended it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the TypeScript typings for the `Proxy` constructor [assumes that the proxy will be the same type as the `target` parameter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5357), even though this is not always true.  There is an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20846) asking for community help in coming up with better typings.

In the absence of that, I think the only way to deal with this is going to be the judicious use of type assertions and the `any` type.  For example, you can change the line with the error to:

```
return new Proxy(context, handler) as IFunction;
```

and that will probably silence the error.  It's not fully type safe, but as long as you're sure about what you're doing, it should be fine.  And you should be able to add that `evaluate()` method to the `IFunction` interface too.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: It's worth reading this comment, which suggests adding a wrapper function that can specify the correct type of the returned value using intersection types. That way, the function itself could contain its type unsafety(?).

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5357#issuecomment-150227751